Equivalent of TS Parameters in Python
In TypeScript I can do this:
function a(b: string): string {
  return b + "Bar";
}

let c: Parameters<typeof a>[0]; // string
c = "Foo";
e = a(d); // FooBar

How do I do Parameters in Python?
Context: in my case now I want to define a function that takes as parameter an object that I can pass to function of a lib I'm using. Unfortunately that lib's types aren't available at runtime, so I can't import them. Contrived:
from somelib import func

def myfunc(arg: XYZ): # I want to type XYZ
    func(arg)


Possible duplicate: How can I import type-definitions from a typeshed stub-file?. Python's parameters (positional-or-keyword, positional-only, keywords-only, *args, **kwargs) are more sophisticated than JS/TS's (positional-only, ...rest), so while ParamSpec is a thing, you can't simply use it the way you want.

Hi, this is called generic types. Check example here https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html
